# Where should I modify the PATH var on OS X?

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

I recently installed MySQL on a new Mac OS 10.6.1 Snow Leopard system. MySQL seems to be running according to the control panel and the output of `ps aux | grep mysql`. However, on the command line the `mysql` command is not available because (I think) the dir `/usr/local/mysql/bin` is not in the PATH.

I could add this to `/etc/bashrc`...

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Yes, OK that worked.

But is that the right way to do it? Should I add it to `/etc/profile` instead? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct way to do it. `/etc/profile` is for login or non-interactive shells

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to set PATH in [~/.MacOSX/environment.plist](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1067.html). You can use [RCEnvironment](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/Bundles.html) to edit environment.plist. One downside of environment.plist is that it doesn't expand environment variables, so you can't append to a variable. The upside is that it works for all applications, not just those run from a terminal.